# How to make a line of code appear multiple time using range() in python

Tags: python, while-loop, range

I would like to make a line of code appear multiple times using range and a while loop, here is an example code and can you please give your answer using this code thanks

```
def surprise:
     counters = 30
     while counters in range(30):
         print("Sorry there is no surprise for you")
         counters = counters - 1
     else:
         print("NOTHING")
```

Comment: which line do you want to appear multiple times?

Answer (score 1):

You're using the wrong loop! This should be a `for` loop; you're doing something once `for` every item (called `counter`) `in` `range(30)`.

```
for counter in range(30):
    print("Number", counter)
else:
    print("NOTHING")
```

This will output:

```
Number 0
Number 1
Number 2
Number 3
Number 4
Number 5
Number 6
Number 7
Number 8
Number 9
Number 10
Number 11
Number 12
Number 13
Number 14
Number 15
Number 16
Number 17
Number 18
Number 19
Number 20
Number 21
Number 22
Number 23
Number 24
Number 25
Number 26
Number 27
Number 28
Number 29
NOTHING
```

This prints `"NOTHING"` because the `for` loop exits normally, without a `break` statement. If you had this code:

```
for counter in range(30):
    if counter == 20:
        break
else:
    print("NOTHING")
```

then `"NOTHING"` would never be printed.

Comment: @Austin It doesn't work. That's like asking what's wrong with the sentence "I **have** going to the shop" - it's the wrong word; that should be "I **am** going to the shop" in order to make sense. It's the same with Python.

Comment: It does work provided `counters` is positive number less than 30, but not the right way of doing as you said.

Comment: @Austin Ok. Here's the full explanation. `while x in y` checks to see if `x` is contained within `y`. So that runs the loop while `counter` is `in` `range(30)`, i.e. is one of `0`, `1`, `2`, ..., `28`, `29`. `counter` starts at `30`, so the loop never runs. But that's probably not what the OP meant.

Comment: Agree. But what I'm saying is since OP is asking like *"...please give your answer using this code."*, this is as simple as replacing `while` in OP's code with `while counters:`.

Comment: @Austin Feel free to post another answer.